# Asymptotic Complexity, Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

For which case  `f(n) != O(g(n))` and `g(n) != O(f(n))`    is true?

I have following answer to this which i could not understand:

Sometimes true: For `f(n) = 1` and `g(n) = ||n ∗ sin(n)||` it is true, while
for any `f(n) = O(g(n))`, e.g. `f(n) = g(n) = 1`, it is not true.

Please someone help in understanding :

1. For which case it is sometimes true? An explanation with example will be much appreciated.
2. What is meaning of "||" in this?

Comment: If `f(n) != O(g(n))` then it must follow that `f(n) = ω(n)`, and this immediately contradicts `g(n) != O(f(n))`. `||` in your example is probably the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

**f(n) != O(g(n))** is true if for any given **k** and any given **N**  there is a **n >= N** such that **f(n) > k*g(n)**.

An example of both **f(n) != O(g(n))** and **g(n) != O(f(n))** being true at the same time would be the following: Lets define **f(n) = 0** for even **n** and **f(n) = n** for odd **n**. Similarly lets define **g(n) = n** for even **n** and **g(n) = 0** for odd **n**. Now obviously **f(n) > k*g(n)*** for all odd **n** no matter how big we choose **k** and similarly **g(n) > kf(n)** for all even **n** no matter how big **k** is.

Your example of **f(n) = 1** and **g(n) = ||n ∗ sin(n)||** would also work, since **g(n)** is oscillating and getting the value **0** for arbitrarily big **n**, but also getting arbitrarily great values which is enough for our definition of **f(n) != O(g(n))** and **g(n) != O(f(n))** since **f** remains the constant function **1**

Comment: are trying to say g(n) = n for odd n and g(n) = 0 for even? n

Comment: No, I am not trying to say that.